# Discover the source of iPhone Push Notification and the data send with it

Tags: ios, iphone, web-applications, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am working with an iPhone *(iOS 11.1.2 (15B202))* application which sends push notifications whenever a certain product is available. When clicked on the notification, only then the iPhone application will redirect you to a page where you can buy it.

I want to create a web-application that does the same thing (redirect you to the buy page when product is available). So I think I need to analyse the push notification in order to find out which data is received and also, I need to find out the source of this data too (so that I can check on that source via my WebApp). I use *Charles Proxy* to intercept requests made by my iPhone to the iPhone application. At first, I thought I would be able to intercept the source of the push notification, but I couldn't find any request for the push notification.

How can I obtain the data sent in that push notification and use it in my WebApp?

Comment: The push notification will come from Apple's severs. They won't send data to your web app

Comment: @Paulw11 That is what I thought, but I should be able to intercept it right?

Comment: How would you intercept it? The notification is sent direct from Apple’s server to the iOS device using an encrypted connection

Comment: with ssl proxying? @Paulw11 you should be able to find out the body of the push

Comment: iOS maintains a single connection to Apple's servers to receive push notifications.  It examines the payload of the notifications received over this connection in order to route them to the correct app on the device.  Apple will almost certainly have implemented certificate pinning on this connection to prevent MITM attacks.  Even if you could use SSL proxying, for the OPs original task of obtaining the push data, they would need to keep their device running behind the SSL proxy and run code on that proxy to talk to their web app